# How to crop a specific rectangle portion(ROI) from an image in OpenCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv, crop, rectangles, roi

Actually I need to crop a rectangle portion in an image. I am having two points p1 and p2 of the rectangle. After cropping the rectangle I need to store that one for further reference.

Comment: This question was already asked here (multiple times). stackoverflow requires that you perform search before posting question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [crop and Save ROI as new image in OpenCV 2.4.2 using cv::Mat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014093/crop-and-save-roi-as-new-image-in-opencv-2-4-2-using-cvmat)

Comment: It's not working for me. Please suggest me if anything else is there.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i know this is an old question, but this could be helpful to someone else having the same problem.

Given a rectangle containing your

```
roi:    Rect 
rect(topLeft_X,topLeft_Y,bottomRight_X,bottomRight_Y);
```

Say the image you want to crop is `detectROI`, than to crop the `roi` given the above rectangle, simply do the following:

```
Mat roi = detectROI(rect);
```

Than to save this image:

```
imwrite("ROI.jpg", roi);
```